# writing a Context free grammar for a language

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata

Hi I have two question about this language:
**L = {a^i b^j c^k | i = 2*j OR j=2*k }**

1)Finding a CFG

2)If in condition part we put **AND** instead of **OR** , is this language remains **CONTEXT FREE** or not ??

thanks.

Comment: Please stick with one question per question.  Also,  what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What research have you done?  Have you read our reference questions on these subjects, on this site? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.  If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $L_{i=2j ~\text{OR} ~ j=2k} = L_{i=2j} \cup L_{j=2k}$. I'll assume you can do the languages with only one condition.
2. If OR turns into AND, then $L = \{a^ib^{2i}c^{4i}\}$. Use [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) to show that $L$ is not context free.